# Print a picture to a specific printer without choosing a printer dialogue

Tags: vb.net, printing

I would simply like to print a picture to a specific printer without choosing the printer from a dialogue box. I have tried the code below and it works well if the printer in windows 10 is set to default ; if another printer is set to default it will print to that printer :( and not to the printer specified in my code.

How can I get the picture to print to the printer I want?

This is my code below :-

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "SAM4S ELLIX30"

    Dim R As Rectangle

    R = New Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200)

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("c:\programs\logo-s.jpg"), R)

End Sub
```

Comment: You must select the printer name *before* you print.  The PrinterSettings get locked-in at the PrintDocument.Print() call and further changes have no effect.  Move this statement before the Print() call.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly !